# How to change the color of "closing tag" or "matching bracket / parenthesis" highlight color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When Visual Studio Code can tell what parenthesis or bracket is related to the one you are near, it draws a white box around both of them:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

I find this color too bright and distracting, making it messy to read when there is a lot of nesting, etc.

Can this color be changed? I don't even know what to call it and thus can't find a setting to turn it off or on, or change the color. Does anyone know what this is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for the matching bracket:

```
"editorBracketMatch.background": "#ff0000",
"editorBracketMatch.border": "#fff",
```

You are specifically referring to the border, you can change its opacity as well in the hex color via:

```
"editorBracketMatch.border": "#fff8",  // or #ffffff80
```

- a fourth value or a 7-8th values to change opacity

I personally like to set both customizations to the same value to get a bit more "padding" around the bracket:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorBracketMatch.background": "#f008",
  "editorBracketMatch.border": "#f008"
}
```

Comment: Wow, I love the red. We'll see how that goes for a while. This is perfect. Thanks.