# How to change the "scope" indicator in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

How can I modify the style of these cursors/indicators? I find them too big and distracting.
The Atom defaut style (simple underline) is IMO better because it gets out of the way.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188214/custom-brace-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912035/how-to-change-the-color-of-closing-tag-or-matching-bracket-parenthesis-hig.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So actually, one can customise colors but cannot change the shape (box vs underline…). It is currently the subject of a [Git issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19534).